# Is "measure" in the definition of Cardinality a plain english or the measure in measure theory?

Tags: terminology

wiki says: [In mathematics, the cardinality of a set is a **measure** of the "number of elements of the set".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality)

Is **measure** here a plain english or the measure in measure theory?

Comment: Plain English...

Comment: It's english. I do think that it is the best word to use in the context; it's unfortunate that it also happens to have a different technical meaning.

Comment: The cardinality is the number of elements in a set. So just plain english measure.

Comment: @Edcookie274 I like the word measure better than number, personally. But yes, you are right.

Comment: In measure theory, we formalize the intuitive notion of "measure" of a geometrical shape. In set theory we formaluize the intuitive notion of "measure" of a collection of objects, i.e. the number of its elements.